# Node js (Express) freezing in mongodb operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a code that accepts a `post` request and inserts a string into `mongodb` database.

```
app.post('/post_comment', function(req, res) {
    Predicts.findOne({'id': parseInt(req.body.id)}, function(err, card) {
        console.log('')
        console.log(card)
        console.log('')
        if (card) {
        Users.findOne( { 'userid': req.user ? req.user.userid : undefined }, function(err, user) {
            console.log(user)
            console.log('')
            Predicts.update({'_id': card._id},
                    {$push : {comments: {login: user ? user.login : 'anonymous', content: '123'}}},
                    function(err, card1) {throw(err);
                             console.log('---')
                              console.log(card1);
                             })
        })
        }})
    res.redirect('back')
    })
```

This code result in total freezing of `node` process. Only restart of the `node` process can help. 
Debugging shows, that first four `console.log` operations work as supposed, but `console.log('---')`  doesn't happen. This means that `Predicts.update` doesn't work, but it is really works, and I can see the result of this request in the database. What's the hitch?

Upd: I have replaced `Predicts.update` to `Predicts.find` but result is still the same. Collback doesn't work, and `node` process freezing.

Upd2: I established that `node` is not freezing, but returns only content that doesn't require to `mongodb`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the node-mongodb docs, the `update` function looks like:

```
collection.update(criteria, objNew, options, [callback]);
```

So if you want to use a callback, it should be the 4th parameter, and the 3rd should be your options (e.g. `multi:true`) or else `{}`.

Comment: I have replaced `Predicts.update` to `Predicts.find` but result is still the same. Collback doesn't work, and `node` process freezing.

Comment: `update` and `find` have different signatures as well; if you use `find`, then the callback should be the 2nd argument.  Did you make that change?

Comment: yes, really, I have changed the signatures. There are many `find` requests in our project and we have not faced with this trouble yet.

Comment: Just noticed the `throw(err)` above that `console.log('---')`.  Can you try logging the value of `err` first?

Comment: As to the source https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js#L576 you can leave the options out and put the callback on third position...

Comment: @scott-gress. Thank you, your comment help me to find the error. I made a really stupid error `throw(err)` instead of `if(err) throw(err)`